# Displaying a monthly archive of blog posts

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, datamapper

I'm trying to create an 'archive'-page for my blog. It should list all blog titles, ordered chronically in reverse order, grouped by month.

I'm using DataMapper which doesn't have a DATE_FORMAT function like MySQL which means I can't simply group within the query. Therefor I see no other way than to do all the hard work in plain Ruby.

This is what I currently have:

```
# GOOD: order of posts within the months are correct
# BAD: order of months is random

@posts = Post.published(:order => :published_at.desc)

@months = {}
@posts.each do |post|
  month_year = post.published_at.strftime("%B %Y")
  @months[month_year] = [] unless @months.has_key? month_year
  @months[month_year] << post
end
```

View:

```
.archive
  - @months.each do |month, posts|
    %h2= month
    %ol
      - posts.each do |post|
        = partial(post)
```

This does what I want except the order of months are messed up because they are contained within an hash. (I'm on Ruby 1.8 so the order of the hash really is random).

How can I make the order of the months correct? I probably need to use an array instead, but I can't figure out what the rest of the code would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Creating random data to similate your DataMapper array
require 'date'
require 'ostruct'

posts = 10.times.inject([]) {|s,i| s << OpenStruct.new(:id => i, :published_at => Date.parse("2010-#{rand(11)+1}-#{rand(25)+1}"), :title => "title #{i}")}

# Your code starts here
ordered_posts = posts.inject({}) do |s,p|
  ym = p.published_at.strftime('%Y-%m')
  s.merge(s[ym] ? {ym=>s[ym]<<p} : {ym=>[p]})
end.sort {|a,b| b[0] <=> a[0]}

# then in your view do
ordered_posts.each do |op|
  puts op[0][-2,2] # your %h2 line
  op[1].sort {|a,b| b.published_at <=> a.published_at}.each do |p|
    puts "   #{p.published_at.strftime('%m/%d/%y')}-#{p.title}" # your partial(posts) line
  end
end
```

produces:

```
wesbailey@feynman:~/code_katas> ruby blogs.rb 
11
   11/10/10-title 9
10
   10/21/10-title 2
09
   09/17/10-title 8
08
   08/21/10-title 1
   08/06/10-title 3
07
   07/06/10-title 6
06
   06/07/10-title 5
05
   05/12/10-title 7
03
   03/16/10-title 4
01
   01/17/10-title 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# posts_controller
@months = @posts.group_by { |post| post.published_at.strftime("%B %Y")}

# archive view
.archive
  - @months.each do |month, posts|
    %h2= month
    %ol
      = render posts
```

Comment: I tried your code, but for some reason the months were still in a seemingly random order as if the group_by didn't have any effect.